# Nullpointerexception attempt to read from null array

Tags: nullpointerexception, mpandroidchart

I made a chart on my android app with MPAndroidChart.
I'm extracting data from my RoomDB.

```
private void reportAnnuale() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> labelsNames = new ArrayList<>();
            int[] colors = new int[12];

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -11);
            int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            calendar.set(year, month, 1, 0, 0, 0);
            Locale.setDefault(Locale.ITALIAN);

            int somma = 0;
            int num = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                colors[i] = R.color.white;
                Long inizio = (calendar.getTimeInMillis() / 1000) * 1000;
                calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, +1);
                Long fine = (calendar.getTimeInMillis() / 1000) * 1000;
                int media = DB.getInstance(getContext()).getValutazioneDao().mediaIntervallo(inizio, fine);
                if (media == 0) num--;
                if (media <= 40 && media > 0) colors[i] = R.color.red;
                if (media > 40 && media <= 70) colors[i] = R.color.yellow;
                if (media > 70) colors[i] = R.color.green;
                barEntries.add(new BarEntry(i, media));
                labelsNames.add("");
                somma += media;
                num++;
            }
            int finalNum = num;
            int finalSomma = somma;

            if(finalNum ==0) return;
            BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries, "Media degli utltimi 12 mesi: " + (finalSomma / finalNum) + " %");
            barDataSet.setColors(colors, context);
            Description description = new Description();
            description.setText("");
            barAnnuale.setDescription(description);
            BarData barData = new BarData(barDataSet);
            barAnnuale.setData(barData);
            XAxis xAxis = barAnnuale.getXAxis();
            xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(labelsNames));
            xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM_INSIDE);
            xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
            xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
            xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
            xAxis.setLabelCount(labelsNames.size());
            xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(270);
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    barAnnuale.invalidate();
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Everything works perfectly but the app rarely crashes due to this exception, the exception refers to external code, no line of my code is reported, log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
    at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.BarChartRenderer.drawDataSet(BarChartRenderer.java:138)
    at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.BarChartRenderer.drawData(BarChartRenderer.java:82)
    at com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarLineChartBase.onDraw(BarLineChartBase.java:237)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22513)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21376)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22238)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4551)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4310)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21367)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22238)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4551)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4310)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22517)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21376)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22238)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4551)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4310)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21367)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22238)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4551)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4310)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22517)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1833)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21376)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22238)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4551)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4310)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21367)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22238)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4551)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4310)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:1975)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21367)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22238)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4551)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4310)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21367)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22238)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4551)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4310)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21367)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22238)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4551)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4310)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21367)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22238)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4551)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4310)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21367)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22238)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4551)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4310)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22517)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:819)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21376)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:559)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:567)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:651)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:4274)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3979)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3240)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2066)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8496)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1076)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:897)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:826)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1061)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8057)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
```

The strangest thing is that the exception rarely occurs...
Why???? Thank you all!!!!

Comment: you have to mention in which line you are getting exception??

Comment: the exception refers to external code, no line of my code is reported

Comment: so, try to show stacktrace(log)

Comment: I updated the question with the full log

Comment: looks like one of your two list was null whenever you access it, you have to check where the problem is?.

Comment: how can they be null if I initialize them at the beginning?